# I have a XML tag that I am submitting I need to only show half of the opening tag for the closing

Tags: c#, xml

I am a rookie just started XML about a week ago, so I apologize if this is an easy question but I have searched on the Stack and cant find my answer.
This is what I currently send

```
<BURGER_REQUEST_WHOPPERVersionID_2.4 _ActionType="No Pickle" _CommentText="">
</BURGER_REQUEST_WHOPPERVersionID_2.4>
```

This is what the company said I need to be sending

```
<BURGER_REQUEST _WHOPPERVersionID_2.4 _ActionType="No Pickle" _CommentText="">
</BURGER_REQUEST>
```

This is is my code using C#, done in Visual Studio

```
  XElement burgerRequestNode = new XElement("BURGERREQUESTVersionID_2.4",

            new XAttribute("_ActionType", "Original"),
            new XAttribute("_CommentText", string.Empty));
        XElement productNode = new XElement("_PRODUCT",
            new XAttribute("_CategoryDescription", burger.ProductDescription));
        XElement typeNode = new XElement("_TYPE",
            new XAttribute("_Identifier", burger.ProductIdentifier));
        productNode.Add(typeNode);
        requestNode.Add(productNode);
```

Comment: That (the second part) is invalid XML.

Comment: Your code doesn't even come close to producing either version of the XML (either version), and the second XML sample is invalid.

Comment: I am a little confused cause the what I am sending example is what the company shows on their end not mine. I got this in an email today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your code won't give you what they want from you.

You need to be sending the attributes and nothing else. Consider something like the following:

```
XElement burgerRequestNode = new XElement("BURGER_REQUEST",
                                new XAttribute("_MISMOVersionID", 2.4),
                                new XAttribute("_ActionType", "No Pickle"),
                                new XAttribute("_CommentText", "Hello world!"));
```

XElement denotes the message or part of the message you're trying to send. XAttribute denotes the elements within a single XML tag that should be set.

I assume you have a typo in what the company wants with the MISMOVersionID, as it doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @Joel Then mark the answer as the correct one, so people stop looking if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending a partial closing tag.  If you look more carefully at the required for,at you'll see that the opening and closing tags are the same, but with attributes added to the opening tag.

The value of _MISMOVersionID seems to be illegal, though

Comment: sorry I fixed it to make it uniform but that is the part I am confused about because it isnt a value at least on the documentation I was sent. Action type is a value and commenttext was a value but thanks for looking